# app updates locked on iphone 6

Tags: performance, iphone

My iphone 6 has 7 apps that need to update. I hit update all, but nothing is happening, it's like they are frozen. The update all is grayed out now. I tried turning off my phone and turning it back on, but no luck. The apps are unusable right now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your internet connection slow?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try an App Store refresh (don't worry you won't lose any content).

1. Open the App Store
2. Tap on the Updates tab (or which one you prefer) repeatedly until you see the app store reloading (usually a blank screen and it will then load.

Does the problem still occur?

Hope this helps,

Tiferrei